# Easily retrieving value from IHTMLProp

Tags: f#, fable-f#

I'm using `Fable.React` and want to retrieve some value from an `IHTMLProp list`.

This currently works, but feels a little tedious:

```cs
let selectInput (attr : IHTMLProp list) options =
    let selectedValue =         
        attr
        |> List.map (function
                       | :? HTMLAttr as a -> 
                            match a with 
                            | Value v -> Some v
                            | _ -> None 
                       | _ -> None)
        |> List.choose id
        |> List.tryHead
```

Is there a simpler way to do this?

In particular I would like to simplify the nested matching expression, but any tips are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify the lookup, you can use `List.tryPick`.

To simplify the matching, you can use Active Patterns.

The code would be:

```
let (| IsHTMLAttr | _ |) (attr: IHTMLProp) =
    match attr with
    | :? HTMLAttr as a -> Some a
    | _ -> None

let selectInput (attrs : IHTMLProp list) options =
    let selectedValue =         
        attrs
        |> List.tryPick (function
           | IsHTMLAttr (Value v) -> Some v
           | _ -> None)
```